Communication between two VMs(bridged mode) where the virtual interfaces of both the VMs are in DPDK mode using pktgen or l2fwd
I have setup,in which two VMs (Vmware workstation plyaer) are connected in bridge mode with host. I have created virtual network adapter and binded that adapter with dpdk using vfio-pci driver.
Now I want to send traffic between these two VMs using pktgen or l2fwd.
I have some hint to achieve by configuring ARP table. But I don't know whole flow.
Can someone guide me or give some resources related to it?
I have created virtual network adapter and binded that adapter with dpdk using vfio-pci driver.
